# I want to append in l1 to l2 when the index is 1

Tags: python, list

I am trying to get the output by using for loops

```
l1 = ["a", "b"]
l2 = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
list1 = []

for i in range(len(l2)):
    for j in range(len(l2[i])):
        if l2[i][j] == 1:
            list1.append(l1[j])
```

I want to get output

```
[[], ["b"], ["a"], ["a", "b"]
```

Comment: What was the problem when you tried to do that?

Comment: index out of range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it:

```
[[l1[i] for i, y in enumerate(x) if y] for x in l2]
```

Or in a for loop:

```
result = []

for x in l2:
    part = []
    for i, y in enumerate(x):
        if y:
            part.append(l1[i])
    result.append(part)
```

Comment: is there a way to do it through for loops?

Comment: @ProgrammingWarrior Added that as well.

Comment: just a question: What does the "for i, y in enumerate(x):" do?

Comment: [enumerate](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html) turns your list into pairs containing `index` and `value`, which in turn help you access the same index elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the desired output you can use the following code:

```
l1 = ["a", "b"]
l2 = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
output = [[l1[j] for j in range(0,len(l1)) if i[j] == 1] for i in l2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way using numpy just in case, you need to compute for large lists :

```
import numpy as np
l3 = [list(l1[np.array(k)]) for k in l2]
```

**Output** :

```
[[], ['b'], ['a'], ['a', 'b']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1 = ["a", "b"]
l2 = [[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
list1 = []

for i in l2:
    tm=[]
    if i[0]==1:
        tm.append(l1[0])
    if i[1]==1:
        tm.append(l1[1])
    list1.append(tm)


print(list1)
```

output

```
 [[], ['b'], ['a'], ['a', 'b']]
```